# Launching Unit Tests from ios-sim doesn't execute all tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ios-simulator, xctest

I'm trying to launch tests from my CI using ios-sim using approach described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Xcode , but instead of `SenTest` I'm using `XCTest` in my application, so last parameter should be not

```
--args -SenTest All
```

but something like

```
-args -XCTest All
```

and if I use such parameter, not all tests are executed. How can I specify executing all tests using XCtest? If I use

```
--args -XCTest -test All
```

none of tests are executed. The full launch command:

```
ios-sim launch Target.app --devicetypeid 'com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s, 8.1' --setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection" --setenv XCInjectBundle="UnitTests.xctest" --setenv XCInjectBundleInto="Target.app/Target" --args -XCTest All "UnitTests.xctest"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 points:

First off, the reason this is likely failing is because your DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is wrong.  You should be using "../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBund
leInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection" rather than "/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBund
leInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection"

Secondly, as of Xcode 6, the supported way of doing what you want is by using simctl:

```
SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection"
SIMCTL_CHILD_XCInjectBundleInto="Target.app/Target"
SIMCTL_CHILD_XCInjectBundle="UnitTests.xctest"
xcrun simctl launch [device udid or "booted"] com.mycompany.myapp -XCTest All "UnitTests.xctest"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think DYDL_INSERT_LIBRARIES path is right because tests are launched.
I will try to launch simulator using xcrun simctl and run tests after

Comment: Jeremy, I have launched tests using simctl, but there is no output about testing and I'm not really sure, that tests are executed.
I have installed and inject bundle from `Debug-iphonesimulator` DerivedData