# xcrun: Is there a way to set environment variable via "xcrun simctl" cli

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7, xcrun, simctl

I am looking for a way to set environment while using xcrun. We could set environment via `xcrun simctl setenv` prior to Xcode 7.0. Now we can only view environment using `xcrun simctl getenv <device> <variable name>`.

I have seen a reference of SIMCTL_CHILD_, but I am not sure how to use it.

```
xcrun simctl spawn
Usage: simctl spawn [-w | --wait-for-debugger] [-a <arch> | --arch=<arch>] <device> <path to executable> [<argv 1> <argv 2> ... <argv n>]
If you want to set environment variables in the resulting environment, set them in the calling environment with a SIMCTL_CHILD_ prefix.
```

> I know that its a simple thing, and I am missing a tiny piece here.

Really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598931/launching-unit-tests-from-ios-sim-doesnt-execute-all-tests) help?

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I tried that already but its not setting up the environment correctly. I am trying it something like `SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES ="<value>" ; SIMCTL_CHILD_XCInjectBundleInto ="<value>" ; … ; xcrun simctl launch …`. But its not working. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `export SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES ="<value>" ; export SIMCTL_CHILD_XCInjectBundleInto ="<value>" ; … ; xcrun simctl launch …` seems to communicate these environments variables to my simulators.

Comment: There has never been a 'setenv' subcommand of simctl.  Please explain where you expect this environment variable to actually be set.  The SIMCTL_CHILD_ environment variables effect the environments of the spawned processes, launched jobs, and boot environments.  It's not really clear what a 'setenv' command would do or even how it would work.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633882/run-xctest-bundle-with-simctl) gives a better understanding of what I was trying to achieve. So the part to be able to set environment is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

In your shell script you can add a line like this:

```
export SIMCTL_CHILD_YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_HERE=1
```

replacing `YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_HERE` with the name of your environment variable.